# Is it dangerous to develop a Django App on Windows 10 and run the production server on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, django, development-environment

I'm using a [Shadow PC](https://shadow.tech) computer. A Windows 10 cloud desktop with the latest configuration to run graphic apps at full res for 30€/mounth. The drawback is that I can't install a virtual machine with Linux for dev.

I have small Django based open source projects. I'm the only one to dev on it.

The production server is a VPS with Ubuntu Server.

Since I can't get Linux on my machine to run the IDE this let me a few choices :
 - Dev on Windows 10 and run the production server on Ubuntu.
 - Dev directly on the production server

None of it seems to be very ideal. I feel like the best would be to devlop locally on Windows. However, will I run into big drawbacks when deploying on Linux ?

Comment: No. Why would you think this? Note, you can run Linux on Windows using [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about), but you don't need to, you can run directly on Windows if you want to. In any case, you should never develop on the production server.

Comment: A big NO. just use a virtual environement eg . `pyenv`, `virtualenv` and `pipenv` for your project and you're good to go. Yes, as daniel said a big NO to develop over production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not because your development server and production server is totally different. And also it does not matter because in production it is more efficient way to use webservers like `apache` or `nginx`.

In addition, Most of the deployments are done in Linux/Ubuntu environments. For that you require **shell** knowledge. But it not put you into big hazards. But best practice is to develop into `ubuntu/linux` and  deploy on the same platform because of this gives you hands on experience with **shell script**.

Yet, It is not dangerous to develop on windows and deploy it on ubuntu/linux. ***You can choose either of them, flexibly***.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is use Docker Container, wherever you put the container will be the same code.

https://www.docker.com/

https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-python-django-web-application

Comment: So you suggest to use a container that is not VM based but has compatibility between Windows and Linux?

Comment: Yes, Docker can be use in a lot of S.O. A Docker Image must be the same wherever you put.